# Covariance and Contravariance for Action Delegates

Tags: c#

I'm stuck, why isn't this working:

```
  var childAction = new Action<CancelCommand>(blabla);
  Action<IDomainCommand> upperAction = (Action<IDomainCommand>) childAction;
```

Why isn't this working if CancelCommand implements IDomainCommand?
By the way: Is this co or contravariance what i'm trying to do here? ;)

thank you in advance
just the best
laurin

**EDIT**
Thank you guys for your very fast responses!

The problem why i need this is because i construct a generic Action Template.
I have the following Interface:

```
IMessageBus.RegisterAction<T>(Action<T> registerAction) where T : IDomainCommand
```

Because i have to build this action on runtime my code lookes as the follwing:

```
var genericExecuteAction = this.GetType().GetMethod("ExecuteCommandAction",
                                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).MakeGenericMethod(commandType);

var actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);
var @delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, this, genericExecuteAction);
var actionDelegate = (Action<DomainCommandBase>)@delegate;

messageBus.Register(actionDelegate);
```

The problem is i need to cast it so that i can pass it to this method.
You see?
Behind the mesasge bus we are using is using RX and unfortunately all the methods there use generics, there a now non-generic-overloads.

Comment: Co- & Contra-variance only works on interfaces, not delegates.

Comment: @Enigmativity: It works on delegates too.

Comment: Thank you i found the answer: instead of casting it i just need to call the Register-Method over reflection as well =)

Answer (score 1):

The type parameter of `Action` is contravariant: you can assign an `Action<object>` to an `Action<string>` because obviously a method that can work on any object can also work on a string.

What you do here is trying to bill a method that works on a `CancelCommand` (derived type) as a method that works on any `IDomainCommand` (base type). This is logically wrong, so the compiler doesn't let you do it -- if it did, you could just invoke `upperAction` passing it a `DifferentTypeOfDomainCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

This is contravariance. This isn't working, because if this will be possible, you could write something like this:

```
interface IDomainCommand { }
class CancelCommand : IDomainCommand { }
class AcceptCommand : IDomainCommand { }

        Action<CancelCommand> a1 = c => { };
        Action<IDomainCommand> a2 = a1;

        var acceptCommand = new AcceptCommand();

        a2(acceptCommand); // what???
```

`a2` points to `a1`, and a1 can't accept `AcceptCommand` argument, because it is not a `CancelCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Hang on, why do you want this to work?

Your `childAction` is something that accepts a `CancelCommand` and does something with it.

But `upperAction` could be invoked on **any** `IDomainCommand`, not just a `CancelCommand`. Supposing the above compiled; what should then happen when I do

```
upperAction(new EditCommand());
```

where `class EditCommand : IDomainCommand` ?

If you attempt an assignment the other way round:

```
        var upperAction = new Action<IDomainCommand>(idc => { });
        Action<CancelCommand> childAction = upperAction;
```

it works and you don't even need a cast. Any `Action<IDomainCommand>` counts as an `Action<CancelCommand>`.

Comment: thank you guys for your fast answer. i answered to your questions by editing my intial question.

Answer (score 0):

Your forgetting how these delegates are being used

```
var childAction = new Action<CancelCommand>(blabla);
Action<IDomainCommand> upperAction = (Action<IDomainCommand>) childAction;
```

means that `upperAction` will at some point in the future be called, passing some form of an `IDomainCommand` object.  You are giving it an function which can only handle `CancelCommand` objects.  But there are (probably) other classes which implement `IDomainCommand`, and `upperAction` could potenially be called with any of them.